# Gather all Python modules used into one folder?

Tags: python

I don't think this has been asked before-I have a folder that has lots of different .py files.  The script I've made only uses some-but some call others & I don't know all the ones being used.  Is there a program that will get everything needed to make that script run into one folder?

Cheers!

Answer (score 6):

```
# zipmod.py - make a zip archive consisting of Python modules and their dependencies as reported by modulefinder
# To use: cd to the directory containing your Python module tree and type
# $ python zipmod.py archive.zip mod1.py mod2.py ...
# Only modules in the current working directory and its subdirectories will be included.
# Written and tested on Mac OS X, but it should work on other platforms with minimal modifications.

import modulefinder
import os
import sys
import zipfile

def main(output, *mnames):
    mf = modulefinder.ModuleFinder()
    for mname in mnames:
        mf.run_script(mname)
    cwd = os.getcwd()
    zf = zipfile.ZipFile(output, 'w')
    for mod in mf.modules.itervalues():
        if not mod.__file__:
            continue
        modfile = os.path.abspath(mod.__file__)
        if os.path.commonprefix([cwd, modfile]) == cwd:
            zf.write(modfile, os.path.relpath(modfile))
    zf.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main(*sys.argv[1:])
```

Answer (score 6):

Use the `modulefinder` module in the standard library, see e.g. http://docs.python.org/library/modulefinder.html

Comment: +1 you can use it as a script like that: python -m modulefinder myscript.py

Answer (score 0):

[Freeze](http://wiki.python.org/moin/Freeze) does pretty close to what you describe. It does an extra step of generating C files to create a stand-alone executable, but you could use the log output it produces to get the list of modules your script uses. From there it's a simple matter to copy them all into a directory to be zipped up 
(or whatever).