# Gather all Python modules used into one folder?

Tags: python

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Gather all Python modules used into one folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/907660/gather-all-python-modules-used-into-one-folder)

I don't think this has been asked before-I have a folder that has lots of different .py files.  The script I've made only uses some-but some call others & I don't know all the ones being used.  Is there a program that will get everything needed to make that script run into one folder?

Cheers!

Comment: Dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/907660/gather-all-python-modules-used-into-one-folder

Comment: Please do not post the same question twice.

Answer (score 1):

Since Python is not statically linked language, this task would be rather a challenging one. Especially if some of your code uses `eval(...)` or `exec(...)`.

If your script is not very big, I would just move it out, make sure that your python.exe does not load modules from that directory and would run the script and add missing modules until it works.

I you have multiple scripts like this, then this manual work is not really the way to go. But in this case also having lots of different .py files in a directory is not a good deployment technique and you should think about packaging them into *installable* modules and install into your python site-packages.

Still you may use [snakefood](http://furius.ca/snakefood/) package to find our the dependencies (has already been discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/508277/is-there-a-good-dependency-analysis-tool-for-python)). Again, it just cannot be 100% accurate, but should give you an easy start.

Answer (score 1):

you should be able to extract the needed information from a so called *call graph*

See for example

- http://pycallgraph.slowchop.com/ or
- http://blog.prashanthellina.com/2007/11/14/generating-call-graphs-for-understanding-and-refactoring-python-code/

Also, [py2exe](http://www.py2exe.org/) converts a python call into an executable and in this process it gathers all used modules. I think py2exe is cross platform

Answer (score 0):

I'd try 2½ solutions, one elaborate and 1½ quick-and-dirty:

- elaborate: a custom import hook, logging all imports
- quick and dirty, part a: `os.utime` the *.py[co]? (`re` notation, not `glob`) files to having access times of yesterday, then run the program and collect all recent access times. Prerequisite: a filesystem that marks access times (by itself and by its mount options).
- quick and dirty, part b: remove all *.py[co] files (same in `glob` and `re` notation), run the program, see which have been created. Prerequisite: user should have write access to the folder.